# Synchronising contacts between iCloud and iOS

Tags: ios, data-synchronization, icloud, contacts

I have a problem with my contacts synching between iPhone and iCloud. There is a number of contacts that appears with the tag iCloud in my phone, although they arent on the iCloud website or my contacts app in OSX.

Here is how the contact looks on my iPhone.
[image]

That same contact does not appear on iCloud.

On bottom of contact says:

[image]

How can I fix this problem, without adding missing contacts manually ?

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From iCloud settings turned off contacts, then back on. Then missing contacts appeared on iCloud although I got double contacts on iPhone. So I close iCloud contacts again and remove iPhone contacts, then back on and contacts sync with iCloud properly without doubles..